# Can't find module "mpir" while unsing CMake generating "gr-ais"

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, mpir

I'm trying to install "[gr-ais](https://github.com/bistromath/gr-ais)" and I get an error while using CMake "**Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR)**":

```
mavo@mavo:~/Dokumente/ais$ cmake gr-ais/
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Checking for module 'mpir >= 3.0'
--   No package 'mpir' found
-- Could NOT find MPIR (missing: MPIRXX_LIBRARY MPIR_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- User set python executable /usr/bin/python3
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (found suitable exact version "3.8.5") 
-- Extracting version information from git describe...
-- Using install prefix: /usr/local
-- Building for version: 21621032 / 0.9.0git
-- 
-- Checking for module SWIG
-- Disabling SWIG because version check failed.
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (found version "3.8.5") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mavo/Dokumente/ais
```

As a result gr_ais is not working:

```
mavo@mavo:~/Dokumente/ais$ ais_rx 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ais_rx", line 6, in <module>
    import ais
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ais'
```

I have installed mpir 3.0 (https://github.com/wbhart/mpir/releases), gnuradio-companion (3.8.1.0), GMP 6.2.1 and libgmp-dev (2:6.2.0+dfsg-4) too. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Mavo! Good SO question shows an effort the author made to solve the problem. How did you research the problem? What is OS you are building on? Have you looked into mpir docs about how to use the library? It may have notes about paths you have to specify.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem: I needed to install gr-ais on /usr and not /usr/local. So just type `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr gr-ais/` I think in /use/local python couldn't find the library... Don't forget to do a `make clean` before.

I did also install some more packages:

```
sudo apt install -y cmake autoconf libtool pkg-config build-essential  libcppunit-dev swig doxygen liblog4cpp5-dev gnuradio-dev gr-osmosdr libosmogsm10  libosmocodec0 libosmogsm-doc libosmosdr0 libosmocodec-doc libosmosdr-dev libosmocoding0 libosmocoding-doc libosmocore libosmocore11 libosmocore-dev libosmocore-doc libosmocore-utils libosmoctrl0 libosmoctrl-doc
```

After all just do: make and sudo make install - ais_rx ist then available for sudo.

**But this didn't solve the missing mpir package. CMake was still complaining.** But gr-ais seems to work now anyway.